# vb.net folder and files only accesible by application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there a way to make a folder and or files only accessible by an application

I remember playing a game where it had a large file with resources in it and it was only accessible to the application.

I am trying to do the same thing.

I have looked into zipping a folder but I don't want to extract the contents to a location, unless that location is accessible only to the application.

I have also looked into encryption, is there a way to keep a whole folder or files encrypted and have the application only able to read it?

I want the application to only have access to certain files.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Restrict a directory that can be used only through a .net Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261021/restrict-a-directory-that-can-be-used-only-through-a-net-application).

Comment: If you want only application be able to use data you need encryption. To be the owner of that folder, your app will have to run as some kind super user and have ownership of that folder. This is just way out of ball park. Or use recommendation from the previous comment.

Comment: I don't think isolated storage will be a solution because the folder is dynamic and sometimes quite large. I don't want it to be pulled onto the user's computer/profile/ every time. The folder is also on a network share.

Comment: If your folder is on network, it can be given access by a single user and to access it your application will have to run under that user logon. So, whoever logs on computer with that logon, will be able to see contents. Other people wouldn't. Unless they are admins in your network.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Even though users can open the file physically created under Isolated Storage its hard to find the file(*Check how the directories are created in the bellow example*) Also You can set the appropriate security policy for the created storage and other applications can not access the same file.

> For desktop apps, isolated storage is a data storage mechanism that
>   provides isolation and safety by defining standardized ways of
>   associating code with saved data. Standardization provides other
>   benefits as well. Administrators can use tools designed to manipulate
>   isolated storage to configure file storage space, set security
>   policies, and delete unused data. With isolated storage, your code no
>   longer needs unique paths to specify safe locations in the file
>   system, and data is protected from other applications that only have
>   isolated storage access. Hard-coded information that indicates where
>   an application's storage area is located is unnecessary.

**Creating Directory and File under Isolated Storage**

`C#`

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User), null, null))
{
    storage.CreateDirectory(@"SampleStorageFolder");
    storage.CreateFile(@"SampleStorageFolder\ReadMe.txt");
}
```

`VB.NET`

```
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
    Using storage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain Or IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly Or IsolatedStorageScope.User), Nothing, Nothing)
        storage.CreateDirectory("SampleStorageFolder")
        storage.CreateFile("SampleStorageFolder\ReadMe.txt")
    End Using
```

Above code will create the Directory and File under Isolated Storage as,

```
C:\Users\agarajah\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\f1fbq2pf.hsm\dkuvmluc.cgn\Url.q4hqkailhblwbougknr2gnmsmovpnjjc\Url.q4hqkailhblwbougknr2gnmsmovpnjjc\Files\SampleStorageFolder\ReadMe.txt
```

**Reading File created under Isolate Storage**

`C#`

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User), null, null))
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(storage.OpenFile("ReadMe.txt", FileMode.Open)))
    {
       string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

`VB.NET`

```
Using storage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain Or IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly Or IsolatedStorageScope.User), Nothing, Nothing)
    Using reader As New StreamReader(storage.OpenFile("ReadMe.txt", FileMode.Open))
        Dim content As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Using
```

**Note**: Trying to read the same file from another application would give FileNotFoundException with the error message "Could not find file 'ReadMe.txt'.".

Answer (score 0):

First thing you could do is make a hidden folder your application browses to.

For the encrypting:
Encrypting a file seems risky for someone without experience.
You could somewhat encrypt the extensions though.
for example file.docx --> file.abc

This way u should not be able to open it yourself,
you could then make an application to know which 'fake extension' compares with which real extension.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: encrypt extension, huh? And then, user goes and clicks (if not done yet) `Show hidden files`. Oh well...

Comment: When you change the .Docx part of a word sheet, you can't open it anymore (pc doesn't know what program to use).

If you would make your app change the extention in a way it can later give it the right extention back you can only open the file's with your app.

Comment: this is the most foolish thing I heard here in some time. It is entertaining even! All I need to do is open a notepad, in menu "open" browse to the file with ANY extension, and this file will open its contents in notepad. By changing extension, you only dissociate file from its original program, so OS doesn't know which program to use - it will give you list of available programs. But in no way you will make it impossible to read this file.

Comment: I totally agree but It would probably achieve what he is looking for. a way to hide certain file's from someone, and as I don't think anyone but a relative would be interested in his file's, I think encoding the extension would do just fine.

Anyways I'm 17 years old and a recreational programmer I'm sure I will not match your knowledge any time soon, Therefor I will not argue any further.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to hurt you or discourage. sounds like one who asked has a production problem. And you can't have anything less then production approach to a production problem.