# How to limit folder/file access to a program only?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, security, directory

Okay, so I am creating a c# winforms application.

I want to write/read from binary data file.  But, I want to put that file in a folder somewhere and I do not want anyone to be able to delete or edit the file.  I only want the program that uses the file to be able to access it.

Is this possible? I looked into MSDN's structure on file security and as I researched it I saw people complain that if you limit the file to a user then that person can just override the privileges and make it editable.

Also, I thought about how this would actually work considering in essence I would like a process to edit the file only and that process could have varying process ID's if it is opened and closed over time, seems tough.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `I only want the program that uses the file to be able to access it.` Serious question: why? Unless you're acting as the machine administrator, you really have no control over what the user does to their own filesystem. If you're worried about the integrity of your app data, then there are other things you can do to verify said integrity when using the data.

Comment: Well my thinking is why would you want anyone to be able to go looking through files, find one that says say "importantData.bin" and open and start messing with it.  If one thing gets messed up then you have lost data integrity as you said.

Comment: Right - so in that case, you can build your own logic (or search online to find a solution) that only accepts 'good' data. This is a better method than trying to somehow lock down the filesystem, which isn't desired from a user perspective.

Comment: Yea I see what you're saying. But, if that happens then you are just saying well I lost the data I had before and can't get it back now. The application deals with important contracts and I cannot afford to just say oh the data's wrong don't open it.. Because if I just do that then I have lost the data that I can't afford to lose.

Comment: Yes, and I understand your concern. That said, if you are VERY concerned about data integrity, you should not be storing it on a client machine; remember that the user has the ultimate control - what if they decide to uninstall the program? Or format the hard drive? If you need to preserve the data without the possibility of a user interfering, you'll need to look at a central storage mechanism of some kind.

Comment: @admdrew I have this as a project requirement.  The customer asked me to make sure that they themselves can't accidentally mess up the data files.  They have also asked me to provide some sort of protection against accidental deletion of files.  I came here looking for a way to limit access to a folder to just my own programs (I just need superficial protection just to remind them that these are sensitive files that shouldn't be messed with).

Comment: @Ben Use read-only and/or hidden files.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this will not satisfy all your requirements you can try [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (System.IO.IsolatedStorage Namespace).

[How to write and read file in IsolatedStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933179/vb-net-folder-and-files-only-accesible-by-application/19946665#19946665)

> The System.IO.IsolatedStorage namespace contains types that allow the
>   creation and use of isolated stores. With these stores, you can read
>   and write data that less trusted code cannot access and prevent the
>   exposure of sensitive information that can be saved elsewhere on the
>   file system. Data is stored in compartments that are isolated by the
>   current user and by the assembly in which the code exists.
>   Additionally, data can be isolated by domain. Roaming profiles can be
>   used in conjunction with isolated storage so isolated stores will
>   travel with the user's profile. The IsolatedStorageScope enumeration
>   indicates different types of isolation. For more information about
>   when to use isolated storage

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent file access while your program is running if you open it exclusively.

However, when the program is not running, the file is no longer protected. So someone would just need to kill the program in order to access the file.

In order to protect the file while your program is not running, you'd need to set up a user account and assign it a password which is only known to the program. Then set the permissions of the file so that only your user can access the file.

However, any administrator can take over the ownership of the file, so even permission protection is useless.

Finally, someone can even take the hard disk out of the PC and read the raw data.

You might also think about whether you want to protect the file or the file content. If the file content is sensitive, think about encryption.

It really depends on your needs, which option to choose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not too worried about anyone reading the data its not sensitive in that regard. I just don't want someone to find the file and either delete it by accident or purpose.  I will look into setting up a user and account permissions. That seems like the only possibility at this point and hope that no one takes over as admin and messes with it.  This wouldn't even be a problem if the machines had internet access, I would just set up a server or something. But they don't...

Comment: If you have NTFS file system, try Alternate Data Streams on your program's executable or DLL. They are almost invisible. You need special tools to see them. Anyone using those tools would also know how to take ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 version 1709 introduced [Controlled Folder Access](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-controlled-folder-access-windows-10-fall-creators-update). This allows you to whitelist applications that can modify certain folders. You cannot restrict Read access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the target filesystem prior to install then setup some file permissions and go from there. The user accessing the folder will need read permissions at minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Run the app under a security group and assign persmissions to the folder and files with that security group. Revoke access for others and make it readonly

Answer (score -1):

well, I have the same issue and I did some research on this subject and I found that secure your information in a accesspoint database or any other Microsoft data base with password and only one specific app that have the password will have the permission to do read/write to these information.