# How to secure localdb on a standalone application?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-express, localdb

I just installed my standalone application with localdb on client machine, and published it using clickonce. It works fine.

My question is: Is my database secured? Because I can see where it is located, and I only want my app to access my database and not other users/local user.

[image]

Note: I am not using SSMS in my development machine. I created my database by just adding a service-based database on my project.

Comment: Anyone who has physical access to that computer and its drive can copy away the `.mdf/.ldf` files and attach them to a SQL Server elsewhere and inspect them. If you have sensitive information in your database, your only line of defense is to use **data encryption** so that someone who gets the files can inspect them, but not make sense of the data contained in them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit folder/file access to a program only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010372/how-to-limit-folder-file-access-to-a-program-only) and [Denying direct access to a folder (only allow through app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822173/denying-direct-access-to-a-folder-only-allow-through-app)

Comment: Very little you can do against a determined attacker with Administrator access

Comment: I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=425ehlBxqo4 about EncryptbyPassPhrase. Is EncryptbyPassPhrase enough security? (This is my first time making a secure database because it is for a client)